# What do I need to create my news app? So I'm able to update it without reuploading the app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, app-store

I'm interested in trying to build an news app as a learning project. My plan is that on my app you can access a few different categories and in those categories there are some text that I myself has written. (Not a URL from a news website or something like that)

But if I made my app and wrote my articles directly in Xcode, I would not be able to update it as soon as I (theoretically) uploaded it to an App store.

Can anybody point me in the direction? so that I can research about the logic behind making such an app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download data from a server. To implement this you should know about [client-server communications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH12-BBCFIHFH). 
Also look at [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsession?language=objc), [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsxmlparser?language=objc) or [NSJSONSerialisation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization), [CodeData](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH2-SW1), [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Timers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000061-SW1), [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilemanager?language=objc).

These classes are needed to implement data downloading, parsing and storing to the phone.

Comment: Andrew do you think Firebase would be able to work as my server then? I have a little bit experience with Firebase.

Comment: I didn't understand what is news (is it your custom news or world news?). But I think if you want to deliver your custom news or want to have some control under a news thread you should create your custom server. You can use Firebase as backend, and don't forget that Firebase delivers sdk for frontend  (for examle for ios and android).

Comment: If you do not want to customise the news thread you can use any rss thread that is delivered by any news portal.